# SendMessage проблема с окном

Tags: c#, winapi

Почему на некоторых окнах не возможно послать сообщение, на примере я взял окно Steam чтобы вписать туда какой либо текст (only English)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

IntPtr ptr = WinAPI.FindWindow(null, "Вход в Steam"); // Сам заголовок окна стима
            if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Окно не найдено");
            }
            else
            {
                IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(ptr, new IntPtr(0), "USurface_2895518", null); // USurface через WinSpy++
                string s = SetForegroundWindow(ptr) + "SoiuC231ouv"; // Тут я походу не правильно фокус для формы ставлю
                SendMessage(child, 0x000C, 0, s);
            }
            Console.Read();
```

Как отправить текст в текстбокс Stem'а?

**Дополнительно**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс `USurface` постоянно меняется, как его отследить?

Comment: Потому что стим (как и подавляющее большинство других гвно-лаунчеров) представляет собой окно браузера на основе хромиума.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что далеко не все интерфейсы построены на базе Windows Forms, и, стало быть, далеко не все поля ввода — те старинные и простые TextBox (или как их там). Есть WPF, есть приложения с отрисовкой через WebKit, есть Qt, да и мало ли что ещё. Причём, если учесть, что Steam кроссплатформенен, тут наверняка использовалось что-то не-виндовое.

Чтобы изменить содержимое поля, можно эмулировать нажатия клавиш (как вариант, копировать текст в буфер обмена и «нажимать» Ctrl+V). Хотя это и паршивое решение, конечно.

Comment: Спс, учту на будущее). А что на счёт отлова класса `USurface`, если он меняется как его отловить? Может можно как-то по другому?

Comment: @ArteS, полагаю, можно просто искать окно с классом, начинающимся на «USurface_», так-то число, видимо, генерируется случайно. Можно попытаться искать окно по занимаемой площади, например. Всё это очень ненадёжно, но вообще таким образом цепляться к чужой программе (особенно с такой системой обновлений, как у Steam), не менее ненадёжно.

Comment: Значит вписать не получиться обычным способом, а вот получить какой либо текст из этого окна возможно? Я пробовал использовать функцию `WM_GETTEXT` вмести со `StringBuilder'ом`, но не смог получить текст из поля ввода.

Comment: @ArteS, `WM_GETTEXT` также работает лишь с обычными контролами из Windows Forms. И вписать, и скопировать можно, эмулируя устройства ввода, и, скорее всего, не иначе (ещё, по идее, можно попробовать встроиться в процесс, но это будет очень непросто).

Answer (score -1):

Для авторизации в Steam можно использовать параметры запуска:

```
steam.exe -login login password
```